# StateMachine - actions on states change

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I wrote the implementation of the state machine, using the Spring guide.

But I can’t achieve any reaction for changing the state, although the states themselves change successfully. Perhaps I misunderstood the goal of the Beans class? I need to achieve automatic execution of the closeDoor() and startMoving() methods when the state changes.

These messages in the methods on the console are not displayed:

```
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.OnTransition;
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.WithStateMachine;

@WithStateMachine
public class Beans {

  @OnTransition(target = "CLOSED_DOOR")
  void closeDoor() {
      System.out.println("closeDoor method");
  }

  @OnTransition(target = "GOING")
  void startMoving() {
      System.out.println("startMoving method");
  }
}
```

Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;;

import java.util.EnumSet;


@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class Configuration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {
    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(States.STAY)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(States.STAY).target(States.CLOSED_DOOR)
                .event(Events.CLOSE_DOOR)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(States.CLOSED_DOOR).target(States.GOING)
                .event(Events.MOVE);
    }
}
```

And the launch (the states are displayed correct in the console, according to the events):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;

public class App {
    @Autowired
    static StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        stateMachine = Builder.getMachine();
        stateMachine.start();

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.CLOSE_DOOR);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[CLOSED_DOOR]

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.MOVE);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[GOING]
    }
```

Dependency is only one.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you maybe post it as a project on github? I will try to help you then.

Comment: @ŁukaszG sure: https://github.com/anabiozzze/testStateMachine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to make it work. Your problem was Spring DI mechanism. You were trying to use `@WithStateMachine` to enable transition listeners but then you were using `.getMachine()` to create the machine object. It will not work like that, you need to decide whether you want to use Spring Context or not. I've created a solution using context, but as well you can leave it and use just manual builder, but then you will need to change your listeners to use a manual method instead of Spring Context annotations.

Change your main class to:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("machine");
        final StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine = context.getBean(StateMachine.class);

        stateMachine.start();
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[STAY]

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.CLOSE_DOOR);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[CLOSED_DOOR]

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.MOVE);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[GOING]
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you and if you understand it.

Comment: Yep, it works, it only remained to add public to the Beans class methods so that they are correctly defined.

Thank you, I understood the logic of statemachine operation by annotations!